# Relating two different expressions for quadrupole moments

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, multipole-expansion

How do we get from the expression

$$\frac{1}{2} (3(\vec{r} \cdot \vec{r}')^2-r'^2 r^2)$$

to

$$\sum_{i,j=1}^3 r_ir_j \frac{1}{2} (3r'_ir'_j-r'^2\delta_{ij})$$

If someone could go step by step and explain I will be very thankful.

Comment: Hi Darkenin. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write the scalar products $(\vec{r}\cdot \vec{r'})$ and $r^2\equiv (\vec{r}\cdot \vec{r})$ explicitly. Knowing that:
$$\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b} = \sum_{i=1}^3 a_i b_i$$
you can rewrite your quantity as:
$${1 \over 2} \left(3\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 r_i r'_i\right)^2 - r'^2 \sum_{i=1}^3 r_i r_i\right)=$$
Now you can write the sum squared as the product of two identical sums with different dummy indices $i,j$:
$$={1 \over 2} \left(3 \sum_{i=1}^3 r_i r'_i \sum_{j=1}^3 r_j r'_j - r'^2 \sum_{i,j=1}^3 r_i r_i\right)=$$
and join the two sums as one sum over two indices. Plus, you can rewrite the term in the second sum using the Kronecker $\delta$:
$$={1 \over 2} \left(3 \sum_{i,j=1}^3 r_i r'_i r_j r'_j - r'^2 \sum_{i,j=1}^3 r_i r_j \delta_{ij}\right)=$$
Finally you can take both the sum and the common factor $r_ir_j$ out of the parentheses:
$$=\sum_{i,j=1}^3r_i r_j{1 \over 2} \left( 3 r'_i  r'_j - r'^2 \delta_{ij}\right)$$